# How to stop windows from sliding down?

Tags: windows

About 10 years ago I had all the windows in my apartment replaced.  Four or five years later, when I would open them to insert a fan or an air conditioner, the top window would slide down 6-12 inches in a few of the windows.  Is there anything that I can do to adjust the windows so they don't slide down?

[update]

I got a couple good answers for wooden windows.  Can anything be done with metal?

Answer (score 3):

The counter balance is not working correctly, but repairing this or replacing it is non-trivial.  Instead, you can pickup a device like this that will create enough friction to hold the window in place.  It should be installed between the window and the frame and is a simple DIY job.

http://www.lowes.com/pd_128860-76018-F+2537_0__?productId=3010767

[image]

Comment: My windows are metal.  They removed everything and put in the window with its casing.  Does this still apply?

Comment: Sorry, this is designed for a wood window.  You will have a difficult time installing this on a metal window, and even if it fits, it may not generate enough friction with metal against metal.  Worst case scenario, you can always fall back to a stick to prop it open.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the siding is wood, I have used wood hardener applied in small amounts, to the edges of the window and the length of the window track, with a q-tip. Worked for me. I *think* maybe it expanded the wood ever so slightly. Also I "worked" the window up and down until it seemed dry to the touch and every 5 min afterward for 30 min. Not exact time but close enough, I didn't want them to stick together.

Answer (score 0):

An older and/or cheaper 100% metal window will have pressure springs similar to what BMitch referenced.  They are either missing, worn-out, or non-functional.